# Read/Write the registers on a GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Is it possible to read/wite from/to the registers on the GPU using OpenCL? I am using a NVIDIA GeForce 9400gt graphics card.

Tried googling out but not much info out there. Can someone tell me if this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: (Much of) the point of OpenCL is to insulate you from knowing all the details of the card. The OpenCL driver will undoubted read/write registers, but a lot of the point is that you don't need to know or care which ones (and can write identical code to run on, say, an ATI/AMD card that uses entirely different registers).

Comment: Deleted my answer because it is partly relevant but not an exact solution to the problem at hand. Putting it up as a comment instead.

@JerryCoffin is correct, you cannot do this using OpenCL. You will need a library like gpuocelot (http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) to help you access the hardware at such a granular level.

Note that gpuocelot only processes PTX (a sort of IL for GPUs). With a decompiler, experience and experimentation it is possible to optimize register usage and/or re-order code at a level that OpenCL cannot allow.

Hope this helps!